# How do I create the necessary function for this multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

The fields in this array are first name, last name, customer ID, balance.  I need to create a function(displayBalance) that returns the balance as dollars and cents when you pass the Customer ID as an argument.
For example:

```
console.log(displayBalance(1234));  // expected output $12354123.56

let customerArr = [

['Ichigo',  'Kurosaki', 23567, 153677345],
['Gin',     'Ichimaru', 1234,  1235412356],
['Shunsui', 'Kyoraku',  1531,  65432467],
['Kisuke',  'Urahara',  543,   63463723562]
];
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service.  Please make an attempt.  If you get stuck, ask a specific question and somebody should be happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

Your data structure is probably not what you need. You can use a variable like the following:

```js
        let customerArr = {
        23567: ['Ichigo',  'Kurosaki', 153677345],
        1234: ['Gin',     'Ichimaru',  1235412356],
        1531: ['Shunsui', 'Kyoraku',   65432467],
        543: ['Kisuke',  'Urahara',   63463723562]};
        
        function displayBalance(a) {
        
          return customerArr[a];
        }
    
        console.log(displayBalance(1234));
```

Answer (score -2):

First, find the array item whose matched with the argument and then return item's last index value.

```
let customerArr = [
['Ichigo',  'Kurosaki', 23567, 153677345],
['Gin',     'Ichimaru', 1234,  1235412356],
['Shunsui', 'Kyoraku',  1531,  65432467],
['Kisuke',  'Urahara',  543,   63463723562]
];

function displayBalance(id){
let customer = customerArr.find(x => x[2] == id);
return custormer ? custormer[3] : 0;
}
```